# Add Extension To Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to add a chrome extension from 2Captcha to my python selenium bot but it doesn't work.

Download the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/captcha-solver-auto-recog/ifibfemgeogfhoebkmokieepdoobkbpo/related?hl=en

and then in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--load-extension=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ifibfemgeogfhoebkmokieepdoobkbpo\3.2.1_0')
driver = Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
```

Can't you just add any extension?

Comment: I have a script that loads an extension in selenium. For one thing, its ```options.add_extension()``` not .add_argument() - Let me know if that fixes it.